# How to Log Errors Thrown from Within Reducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to Redux and struggling a bit to get error messages logged to the console. I'm using React, Redux Toolkit, and TypeScript.

Here is an example of a reducer I've written:

```
// Reducer
const removeResourceReducer = (state: ResourceCounts, action: ResourceAction) => {
  const { id, amount } = action.payload;
  assertIsPositive(amount);
  const has = state[id] ?? 0;
  if (amount > has) {
    throw new Error(`Trying to take ${amount} ${id} from global resources only containing ${has}`);
  }
  state[id] = has - amount;
  if (state[id] === 0) {
    delete state[id];
  }
  return state;
}

// Assertion functions
export const assert = (condition: any, msg: string): asserts condition => {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(`Assertion Error: ${msg}`);
  }
}

export const assertIsPositive = (num: number) => {
  return assert(num > 0, `Expected a positive number, but got ${num}`);
}
```

As you can see, if I were to pass in an amount less than 1 or an amount greater than the number of resources available, an error is thrown. I want this error to be logged to the console so I can check it in devtools, but when I pass an invalid number, nothing is logged. To accomplish this, I attempted adding a custom middleware which wrapped `next(action)` in a try / catch block, where the catch called `console.error(err)`, and I also tried wrapping my root component renderer in a try / catch to get the same result - logging any unhandled error in the app.

Googling hasn't helped me so far, so could anyone give me any ideas? I assume something in Redux or Redux Toolkit is catching the error, but I don't know what it's doing with the info.

Answer (score 1):

The React Redux docs provide some [middleware examples](https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware#seven-examples), one of which is "crash reporter".

> ```
> /**
>  * Sends crash reports as state is updated and listeners are notified.
>  */
> const crashReporter = store => next => action => {
>   try {
>     return next(action)
>   } catch (err) {
>     console.error('Caught an exception!', err)
>     Raven.captureException(err, {
>       extra: {
>         action,
>         state: store.getState()
>       }
>     })
>     throw err
>   }
> }
> ```

A simple implementation could be something like the following:

```js
const errorLogger = store => next => action => {
  try {
    return next(action);
  } catch(error) {
    // log the error/send to analytics/crashlytics/etc
    throw error;
  }
};
```

```js
configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
      errorLogger,
    ),
  preloadedState,
});
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-log-errors-thrown-from-within-reducers]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is exactly what I tried using middleware. The error was never logged. The action failed, which was desired, but nothing was sent to the console.

Comment: @Sabelyn I use something similar to catch/handle uncaught errors in my store. I'll see about working on a running demo.

Comment: @Sabelyn I've updated my answer with a small demo. Please do check it out when you've time.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to put together this demo. Unfortunately, I'm blind and Codesandbox is not accessible, so I'm unable to view the files. I don't know why what I'm doing isn't working, but maybe I'll just stumble across the reason eventually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sabelyn Ack, that's a major bummer about Codesandbox's accessibility. Welcome, I'm happy to help. Cheers and good luck though.